# reactive forms validation not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have reactive form set up as follows (HTML) -

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text"
         class="form-control" id="name"
         placeholder="enter name"
         formControlName="name"/>
  <div class="alert-danger">
    {{myForm.get('name').valid}} 
    {{myForm.get('name').pristine}}
 </div>
</form>
```

For some reason, when I interact with the control, on Internet Explorer 11, the valid and pristine values are not updated.
In Chrome/FF, it is working as expected - form control state is changed.

Has anyone faced similar problem before?

Comment: What if you change formcontrolname and id="name" to "firstName". What does inspect show?

Comment: Tried that, not working

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: No errors. It just does not work on IE.

Comment: Ok, looks like the issue was with placeholders. (IE placeholder issue) and accidentally, while posting this question, I removed placeholder from input so editing question now.

Comment: add `name="name"`